# ¿Detectar un número de 13 dígitos en una URL y en HTML?

Tags: php, regex, php7

Mi objetivo es crear una expresión regular que sea capaz de detectar un número de 13 dígitos.

La verdad es que se me va mal esto de las expresiones regulares, no obstante, he estado leyendo información en los siguientes enlaces:

[Ejemplos de Expresiones Regulares](http://php.net/manual/es/regex.examples.php)

[Buscamos patrones con expresiones Regulares en PHP](https://maugelves.com/expresiones-regulares-en-php/)

Reconozco que quizás, esta pregunta moleste a varios, pero es que ya dediqué tiempo en buscar la expresión y no he encontrado nada.

**Ejemplos:**

https://wwww.example.com/productos=12&list=50&c=1234567891234 -> Detectado

https://wwww.example.com/productos=12&list=50 -> NO Detectado

Encontré la siguiente expresión que filtra 1 dígito, ahora sólo necesitaría para filtrar 13.

```
\{0-9}$
```

Comment: ¿podrías indicar qué intentaste?

Comment: He leído sobre expresiones regulares, pero no me entero como hacerlo. Es bastante complejo

Comment: empieza a poco a poco, casos fáciles. Si no, difícilmente aprenderás. Por ejemplo, `^[0-9]$` coge cadenas de exactamente un número.

Comment: ¿y dónde se indica la cantidad de números? o sea, ¿cómo sería para 2 números por ejemplo?

Comment: investiga un poco, Carlos. Hay fantásticos tutoriales que te proporcionarán más conocimiento que esperar a que alguien te responda la pregunta : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En PHP, utliliza [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php)

```
$url1 = "https://wwww.example.com/productos=12&list=50&c=1234567891234";
$url2 = "https://wwww.example.com/productos=12&list=50&c=12345A67891234";
$url3 = "https://wwww.example.com/productos=12&list=50";
echo preg_match("/[0-9]{13}/", $url1); // Muestra: 1
echo preg_match("/[0-9]{13}/", $url2); // Muestra: 0
echo preg_match("/[0-9]{13}/", $url3); // Muestra: 0
```

---

Explicación:

- `[0-9]` busca carácteres entre el 0 y el 9 (dígitos).
- `{13}` busca 13 occurrencias de lo que hemos puesto previamente, por tanto:
- `[0-9]{13}` buscará 13 dígitos seguidos.

Comment: Muchas gracias :)